# SubSonic 3.0 Simple Repository Adding a DateTime Property To An Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3

I am trying out SubSonic to see if it is viable to use on production projects. I seem to have stumbled upon an issue whith regards to updating the database with default values (String and DateTime) when a new column is created.

If a new property of DateTime or String is added to an object.

```
public class Bug
{
    public int BugId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Overview { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrackedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime RemovedDate { get; set; }
}
```

When the code to add that type of object to the database is run

```
var repository = new SimpleRepository(SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);           

repository.Add(new Bug()
{
    Title = "A Bug",
    Overview = "An Overview",
    TrackedDate = DateTime.Now
});
```

it creates the following sql:

```
UPDATE Bugs SET RemovedDate=''01/01/1900 00:00:00''
```

For some reason it is adding double 2 single quotes to each end of the string or DateTime.

This is causing the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - Incorrect syntax near '01'

I am connecting to SQL Server 2005

Any help would be appreicated as apart from this issue i am finding SubSonic to be a great product.

---

I have created a screen cast of my error [here](http://www.screencast.com/users/blounty/folders/Jing/media/dd809d34-6cab-49c7-987a-7d7cccecb3be):

Comment: Is this causing an error or are you wondering why the RemovedDate is being set to that value?
If it is causing an error, which database are you using and what's the error?

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam, it is causing an error which i have added into the question.

Comment: @Blounty: You don't need backticks in code **blocks**. Four space prefix is enough. I removed those for you.

Comment: Can you post the full SQL that the repo.Add generates. I'm confused as to why this is causing an UPDATE when it should do an INSERT

Comment: It is causing an update as it is an NOT NULL column and as such has to populate any preceding rows with default data.

Comment: So does SubSonic execute that UPDATE automatically when you call Add or are you doing something explicitly to cause it?

Comment: Subsonic is doing that call automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug and the dual quotes was introduced a few revs back. I'm fairly certain this has been fixed > 3.0.0.3 so if you want to grab the current drop it should be dealt with.

Sorry for the confusion - but as you have found out you can set the value on create and this will sort the problem. In addition you can do what andymeadows suggests and this will make the field nullable (which is probably more accurate).

Anyway - we'll have this fixed soon :). I'm trying to find a job and don't have too many cycles to spend merging branches :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you can commute to nottingham, england I'm sure we can arrange a position for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the type of RemovedDate from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`

```
public class Bug
{
    public int BugId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Overview { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrackedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RemovedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But i want the field to be Not Null. if i did that it would just make it Nullable.

Answer (score 1):

OK this looks like it's definitely a bug, you don't say whether there's a WHERE clause on that UPDATE statement but if there isn't it's even more of one. Please report it as an issue to [github](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues) with a test case to replicate.
In the meantime you can get around this by setting the value of RemovedDate in code e.g.

```
repository.Add(new Bug()
{
  Title = "A Bug",
  Overview = "An Overview",
  TrackedDate = DateTime.Now
  RemovedDate = DateTime.Now // Set it as required here Now's just an example
});
```